# Rake aborted! undefined method `jobs_to_be_started' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

This is the rake task I am trying to run

```
desc "This task changed the status of started jobs"
task :start_status => :environment do
   jobs_to_be_started = Job.find_all_by_status("Started")
   jobs_to_be_started do |job|
     job.status = "Running"     
     job.saved
   end
end
```

And this is the error I am receiving

```
Rake aborted! undefined method `jobs_to_be_started' for main:Object
```

Have  had a google and can't see an obvious answer, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you've missed an iterator (`each` for example)?

```
desc "This task changed the status of started jobs"
task :start_status => :environment do
   jobs_to_be_started = Job.find_all_by_status("Started")
   jobs_to_be_started.each do |job|
     job.status = "Running"     
     job.save
   end
end
```

And also you will probably get an error on job.saved, is that a misprint? i would suggest you to use `update_attributes` here, like

```
jobs_to_be_started.each do |job|
  job.update_attributes :status => "Running"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code from your example is an invocation of the method `jobs_to_be_started`:

```
jobs_to_be_started do |job|
  job.status = "Running"     
  job.saved # If you don't define `saved` method yourself it should be `save`
end
```

As far as methods are always invoked on objects and you did not specified an object, `jobs_to_be_started` is invoked on `self`. In your case `self` is the main `Object` (context for code ouside class/module definition). 
Main Object does not define `jobs_to_be_started` method and this is why you get this error.

From your code I assume that you expect to call each job in `jobs_to_be_started` list, so you most likely want to do something like this:

```
jobs_to_be_started.each do |job|
  job.status = "Running"     
  job.saved
end
```

Here you call `each` method (and associate this call with the block) of `jobs_to_be_started` object.